# MediaElement.js lacks keyboard control for captions options, won't pass section 508

Tags: keyboard, accessibility, mediaelement.js, mediaelement, captions

I have a website that displays videos using MediaElement.JS
It has been flagged for not being accessible because you cannot change the captions options using a keyboard only.

Here is MEJS website: http://mediaelementjs.com/examples/?name=translation
Using a keyboard, if you tab to the CC button, the options for "English" and "None" pop up, but there is no way to select either option using a keyboard.

Is there a keyboard function for this that I'm not aware of, or is there a way to make the button simply toggle the captions from "English" to "Off"?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Ah found this answer in a Google Group.
Just add this line into your MEJS options "toggleCaptionsButtonWhenOnlyOne: true"

Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mediaelementjs/1LQD8SzG8mQ